# Can graph database query "nodes that a given node has no relationship with"?

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, arangodb, amazon-neptune

I am working on a dating app where users can "like" or "dislike" other users and get matched.
As you can imagine the most important query of the app would be:
`Give me a stack of nearby user profiles that I have NOT liked/disliked before`.

I tried to work on this with a document database (Firestore) and figured it's simply not suitable for such kind of application and hence landed in the graph database world which is new and fascinating to me.

I understand that by nature a graph database retrieves data by tracing through the relationships and make relationships first-class citizens. My question now is that what if the nodes that I am trying to get are those with **no relationship from the given node**? What would the query look like? Can anyone provide an example query?

**Edit:**
- added `nearby` criteria to the query statement

Comment: As you state in your last paragraph, the nature of the problem you are trying to solve isn't really "graph". It seems that you want to create a list of "possibles" by taking all of the nodes in the database and subtracting from that list, the current user and all of the nodes that are currently linked to the current user. Without some other grouping or ordering feature like "just the nodes that have arrived in the last 7 days", this might not scale well.

Comment: Hi @djhallx, thanks for your reply. I am not sure if I understand you correctly but in the scenario of a dating app I believe the grouping could be by geolocation, i.e. a user would only be interested in those "unlinked" users geographically near him/her. Does this make it more scalable?

Comment: Consider the following... When a user joins the dating app community they state their interests. Interests are implemented as nodes in the graph and new users would be linked to those interest nodes. Then when an existing user logs into their account and says "show me new possibilities" you execute a graph query that shows all of the paths from themselves through all of their interest nodes to all other person nodes whose "join date" is newer than the last time the query was run. This makes it a graph query and very easy to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is definitely possible, here is a query example :

```
MATCH (me:Profile {name: "Chris"})
MATCH (other:Profile) WHERE NOT (other)-[:LIKES]->(me)
```

As stated in the comments of your original question, on a large dataset it *might* not scale well, that said it is pretty uncommon that you would use only one criteria for matching, for example, the list of possible profiles to match from can be grouped by :

- geolocation
- profiles in depth 2 ( who is liking me, then find who other people they like, do those people like me ? )
- shared interests
- age group
- skin color
- ...